# Is it possible to tag a user/page through Facebook open graph api?

Tags: ios, facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270588/how-to-tag-user-page-in-facebook-post-to-property-using-graph-api-no-php-or-jav) on SO as well as some other links on the web but they all seem outdated and seem to indicate that FB has not yet exposed this through the Open Graph API and i couldnt find anything to the contrary on the web. I am trying to find a way to post an image to a users wall *and* be able to tag multiple users in the post title or caption?

Is there still no way to do this through the api or somehow achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tagging user/page in photo caption

This is not possible through the *Graph API*, and *as far as I know* the old `@[user_id:0:link_text]` is currently unavailable. Sadly I'm going to say that it is not possible at the time of writing this post.

<sup>I'll update this post with relevant info if I come across any.</sup>

---

#### Tagging user/page in Photo

This is possible through the *Graph API*.

The documentation for how to accomplish what you are looking for is located under the headline *"**tags**"* if you follow the link below:

- **[developers.facebook.com - Core Concepts › Graph API › Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)**

---

[image: facebook graph api tag photo documentation]

Comment: Thx for the quick response but from what i understand this is for tagging users within photos. What i am trying to accomplish is tagging a page to a post similar to what happens when you type @ and it starts autocompleting a user or page within Facebooks own post text box which is different from tagging a user in a photo.

Comment: @s.newave when reading your post it seems that you wanted something else, but no; there is currently no method of properly tagging a user in a title/caption using the graph API. Post uploaded with new information.